# Animación con OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

El problema que tengo es que deseo que se vea cómo se rota un triángulo en OpenGl. Mi profesor nos dijo que uilicemos la función `glutIdleFunc(diplay)` de la API de OpenGL, pero no se anima en triángulo y no sé cómo utilizarla.

anexo mi código

```
#include<math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/GLUT.h>
#define TAM 3
#define PI 3.1416

typedef struct
{
    double x;
    double y;
}vertice;


void init(void);
vertice centrode(vertice[]);
void determinar_matrices_identidad(float[][TAM], float[][TAM]);
void determina_matrices_traslaciones(float[][TAM], float[][TAM], float, float, float, float);
void determinar_matriz_rotacion(float[][TAM], float);
void matriz_traslacion_inversa(float[][TAM]);
void multiplicaion_matrices(float[][TAM], float[][TAM], float[][TAM]);
void multiplicacion_vector_matriz(float[][3], vertice *);
void traslacion(float[][TAM], vertice[], vertice *);
void rotacion(float, vertice[], vertice *);
void dibujar_linea(vertice, vertice);
void dibujar_triangulo(vertice[], vertice);
void display(void);

float matriz_rotacion[TAM][TAM], matriz_traslaUser[TAM][TAM], matriz_traslaSis[TAM][TAM];
float matriz_a[TAM][TAM], matriz_b[TAM][TAM];
float vect[TAM];
float incx, incy;
float tx_usuario = 20, ty_usuario = 30;

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-300, 300, -300, 300);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

////Operaciones para el traslado y rotación//////////////////////////////////////////
vertice centroide(vertice triangulo[])
{
    vertice punto = {(triangulo[0].x + triangulo[1].x + triangulo[2].x)/TAM, (triangulo[0].y + triangulo[1].y + triangulo[2].y)/TAM};

    return punto;
}

void determinar_matrices_identidad(float matriz_a[][TAM], float matriz_b[][TAM])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < TAM; j++)
        {
            if(j == i)
            {
                matriz_a[i][j] = 1;
                matriz_b[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                matriz_a[i][j] = 0;
                matriz_b[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
}

void determina_matrices_traslaciones(float matriz_sistema[][TAM], float matriz_usuario[][TAM], float tx_sis, float ty_sis, float tx_user, float ty_user)
{
    determinar_matrices_identidad(matriz_sistema, matriz_usuario);

    matriz_sistema[0][2] = tx_sis;
    matriz_sistema[1][2] = ty_sis;

    matriz_usuario[0][2] = tx_user;
    matriz_usuario[1][2] = ty_user;
}

void determinar_matriz_rotacion(float matriz[][TAM], float tetha)
{
    matriz[0][0] = cos(tetha);
    matriz[0][1] = -1 * sin(tetha);
    matriz[0][2] = 0;

    matriz[1][0] = sin(tetha);
    matriz[1][1] = cos(tetha);
    matriz[1][2] = 0;

    matriz[2][0] = 0;
    matriz[2][1] = 0;
    matriz[2][2] = 1;
}

void matriz_traslacion_inversa(float matriz[][3])
{

    matriz[0][2] *= -1;
    matriz[1][2] *= -1;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void multiplicaion_matrices(float A[][TAM], float B[][TAM], float C[][TAM])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < TAM; j++)
        {
            C[i][j] = 0;

            for(int k = 0; k < TAM; k++)
                 C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
}

void multiplicacion_vector_matriz(float matriz[][TAM], vertice *punto)//retorna el punto de traslación con respecto a la traslación del sistema
{
    float vect[TAM], total[TAM];

    vect[0] = punto->x; vect[1] = punto->y; vect[2] = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < TAM -1 ; i++)
    {
        total[i] = 0;

        for(int j = 0;  j < TAM; j++)
            total[i] = total[i] + vect[j]*matriz[i][j];
    }

    punto->x = total[0];
    punto->y = total[1];
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

////Funciones para las transformaciones//////////////////////////////////////////////
void traslacion(float matriz_traslacion[][TAM], vertice triangulo[TAM], vertice *pivote)
{
    multiplicacion_vector_matriz(matriz_traslacion, pivote);

    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
        multiplicacion_vector_matriz(matriz_traslacion, &triangulo[i]);
}

void rotacion(float tetha, vertice triangulo[], vertice *pivote)
{
    determinar_matrices_identidad(matriz_a, matriz_b);
    determinar_matriz_rotacion(matriz_rotacion, tetha);
    determina_matrices_traslaciones(matriz_traslaSis, matriz_traslaUser, -1 * pivote->x, -1 * pivote->y, tx_usuario, ty_usuario);

    traslacion(matriz_traslaSis, triangulo, pivote);
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
        multiplicacion_vector_matriz(matriz_rotacion, &triangulo[i]);
    matriz_traslacion_inversa(matriz_traslaSis);
    traslacion(matriz_traslaSis, triangulo, pivote);
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

////Dibujado de elementos ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void dibujar_linea(vertice v1, vertice v2)
{
    double x = v1.x, y = v1.y;
    double xfinal = v2.x, yfinal = v2.y;
    double dx = xfinal - x;
    double dy = yfinal - y;
    double paso;

    if(abs(dx)>abs(dy))
        paso = abs(dx);
    else
        paso = abs(dy);

    incx = dx /paso;
    incy = dy /paso;

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2d(floor(x),floor(y));
    glEnd();

    for(int k =1; k<= paso;k++)
    {
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glVertex2d(floor(x),floor(y));
        glEnd();

        x +=incx;
        y +=incy;
    }
}

void dibujar_triangulo(vertice triangulo[], vertice pivote)
{
    dibujar_linea(triangulo[0], triangulo[1]);
    dibujar_linea(triangulo[1], triangulo[2]);
    dibujar_linea(triangulo[2], triangulo[0]);

    //Dibujamos el centroide
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2d(pivote.x, pivote.y);
    glEnd();
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void display(void)//Función para mostrar el triángulo
{
    vertice triangulo[TAM] = {{50, 40}, {150, 40}, {75, 100}};
    vertice pivote = centroide(triangulo);//es más que obvia esta parte
    float tetha = 2.0;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1 ,1 ,1);
    glPointSize(1);

    //dibujar_triangulo(triangulo, pivote); //dibujamos el triángulo inicial
    rotacion(tetha * PI/180, triangulo, &pivote);
    dibujar_triangulo(triangulo, pivote);

    //Dibujamos el origen
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);//SE INIZIALIZA LAS VARIABLES DE ENTORNO EN UN SOLO BUFFER Y COLOREA RGB
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);// se define el tamaño de la ventana
    glutInitWindowPosition(50,50); // se define las coordenadas inicilaes donde aparacera la ventana
    glutCreateWindow("Practica TAM ");//crea una ventana y se le coloca una leyenda hola mundo
    init();                          //Funcion de servicio para inizializar parametros del ambiente grafico
    glutDisplayFunc(display);          // se define cula es la funcion que redibujara el ambiente grafico
    glutIdleFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya pude arreglar este problema. 
Después de ver unos cuantos vídeos en YouTube, me di cuenta que lo único que no tenía que hacer era actualizar la variable "tetha" e incrementar la rotación para dar un efecto de traslación y rotación que se irpan dibujando cuando se invoque el método `glutIdleFunc()`, que lo que hace es forzar a dibujar lo que está en el búfer de OpenGL aunque no haya algún evento de usuario.

Dejo mi código para que sea de utilidad y puedan utilizarlo inclusive

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/GLUT.h>
#define TAM 3
#define PI 3.1416

typedef struct
{
    double x;
    double y;
}vertice;

void init(void);
vertice centrode(vertice[]);
void determinar_matrices_identidad(float[][TAM], float[][TAM]);
void determina_matrices_traslaciones(float[][TAM], float[][TAM], float, float, float, float);
void determinar_matriz_rotacion(float[][TAM], float);
void matriz_traslacion_inversa(float[][TAM]);
void multiplicaion_matrices(float[][TAM], float[][TAM], float[][TAM]);
void multiplicacion_vector_matriz(float[][3], vertice *);
void traslacion(float[][TAM], vertice[], vertice *);
void rotacion(float, vertice[], vertice *);
void dibujar_linea(vertice, vertice);
void dibujar_triangulo(vertice[], vertice);
void display(void);

float matriz_rotacion[TAM][TAM], matriz_traslaUser[TAM][TAM], matriz_traslaSis[TAM][TAM];
float vect[TAM];
float incx, incy;
float tx_usuario = 0, ty_usuario = 0; //valores finales: x = 20, y = 30
float tetha = 2.0;

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, 300, 0, 300);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

////Operaciones para el traslado y rotación//////////////////////////////////////////
vertice centroide(vertice triangulo[])
{
    vertice punto = {(triangulo[0].x + triangulo[1].x + triangulo[2].x)/TAM, (triangulo[0].y + triangulo[1].y + triangulo[2].y)/TAM};

    return punto;
}

void determinar_matrices_identidad(float matriz_a[][TAM], float matriz_b[][TAM])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < TAM; j++)
            if(j == i)
            {
                matriz_a[i][j] = 1;
                matriz_b[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                matriz_a[i][j] = 0;
                matriz_b[i][j] = 0;
            }
}

void determina_matrices_traslaciones(float matriz_sistema[][TAM], float matriz_usuario[][TAM], float tx_sis, float ty_sis, float tx_user, float ty_user)
{
    determinar_matrices_identidad(matriz_sistema, matriz_usuario);

    matriz_sistema[0][2] = tx_sis;
    matriz_sistema[1][2] = ty_sis;

    matriz_usuario[0][2] = tx_user;
    matriz_usuario[1][2] = ty_user;
}

void determinar_matriz_rotacion(float matriz[][TAM], float tetha)
{
    matriz[0][0] = cos(tetha);
    matriz[0][1] = -1 * sin(tetha);
    matriz[0][2] = 0;

    matriz[1][0] = sin(tetha);
    matriz[1][1] = cos(tetha);
    matriz[1][2] = 0;

    matriz[2][0] = 0;
    matriz[2][1] = 0;
    matriz[2][2] = 1;
}

void matriz_traslacion_inversa(float matriz[][3])
{

    matriz[0][2] *= -1;
    matriz[1][2] *= -1;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void multiplicacion_vector_matriz(float matriz[][TAM], vertice *punto)//retorna el punto de traslación con respecto a la traslación del sistema
{
    float vect[TAM], total[TAM];

    vect[0] = punto->x; vect[1] = punto->y; vect[2] = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < TAM -1 ; i++)
    {
        total[i] = 0;

        for(int j = 0;  j < TAM; j++)
            total[i] = total[i] + vect[j]*matriz[i][j];
    }

    punto->x = total[0];
    punto->y = total[1];
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

////Funciones para las transformaciones//////////////////////////////////////////////
void traslacion(float matriz_traslacion[][TAM], vertice triangulo[TAM], vertice *pivote)
{
    multiplicacion_vector_matriz(matriz_traslacion, pivote);

    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
        multiplicacion_vector_matriz(matriz_traslacion, &triangulo[i]);
}

void rotacion(float tetha, vertice triangulo[], vertice *pivote)
{
    determinar_matriz_rotacion(matriz_rotacion, tetha);
    determina_matrices_traslaciones(matriz_traslaSis, matriz_traslaUser, -1 * pivote->x, -1 * pivote->y, tx_usuario, ty_usuario);

    traslacion(matriz_traslaSis, triangulo, pivote);
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    {
        multiplicacion_vector_matriz(matriz_rotacion, &triangulo[i]);
        multiplicacion_vector_matriz(matriz_traslaUser, &triangulo[i]);
    }

    matriz_traslacion_inversa(matriz_traslaSis);
    traslacion(matriz_traslaSis, triangulo, pivote);
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

////Dibujado de elementos ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void dibujar_linea(vertice v1, vertice v2)
{
    double x = v1.x, y = v1.y;
    double xfinal = v2.x, yfinal = v2.y;
    double dx = xfinal - x;
    double dy = yfinal - y;
    double paso;

    if(abs(dx)>abs(dy))
        paso = abs(dx);
    else
        paso = abs(dy);

    incx = dx /paso;
    incy = dy /paso;

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2d(floor(x),floor(y));
    glEnd();

    for(int k =1; k<= paso;k++)
    {
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glVertex2d(floor(x),floor(y));
        glEnd();

        x +=incx;
        y +=incy;
    }
}

void dibujar_triangulo(vertice triangulo[], vertice pivote)
{
    dibujar_linea(triangulo[0], triangulo[1]);
    dibujar_linea(triangulo[1], triangulo[2]);
    dibujar_linea(triangulo[2], triangulo[0]);
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void display(void)//Función para mostrar el triángulo
{
    vertice triangulo[TAM] = {{50, 40}, {150, 40}, {75, 100}};
    vertice pivote = centroide(triangulo);//es más que obvia esta parte

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1 ,1 ,1);
    glPointSize(1);

    //dibujar_triangulo(triangulo, pivote); //dibujamos el triángulo inicial
    rotacion(tetha * PI/180, triangulo, &pivote);
    dibujar_triangulo(triangulo, pivote);

    //Dibujamos el origen
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glEnd();

    if(tx_usuario <= 70 && ty_usuario <= 70) //La animación de rotación y trasación se detendrá cuando llegue al verctor de traaslación (70, 70)
    {
        tetha += 0.05;
        tx_usuario += 0.05;
        ty_usuario += 0.05;
    }

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);//SE INIZIALIZA LAS VARIABLES DE ENTORNO EN UN SOLO BUFFER Y COLOREA RGB
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);// se define el tamaño de la ventana
    glutInitWindowPosition(50,50); // se define las coordenadas inicilaes donde aparacera la ventana
    glutCreateWindow("Practica TAM ");//crea una ventana y se le coloca una leyenda hola mundo
    init();                          //Funcion de servicio para inizializar parametros del ambiente grafico
    glutDisplayFunc(display);          // se define cula es la funcion que redibujara el ambiente grafico
    glutIdleFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no rota por completo.. le falta una linea de código?

Comment: Me parece curioso que usando el fixed pipeline no uses `glRotatef`, `glTranslatef` y demás funciones obsoletas.